# Unable to prompt to install plugin when loading page inside of an iframe

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm working on a portal to a page where customers can see the streaming video of their security cams. I just currently have a page with our logo with an iframe containing the proper surveillance page. It works fine, except for one major problem. If the plugin isn't already installed, it will never prompt to load the H264 Streaming Viewer from AVTECH, as long as its being loaded through an iframe.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: You probably need IE, right? Cuz otherwise you could use `navigator.plugins`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do they have to be embedded via iframes? You may also consider injecting them via `<object>` or if they’re supposed to be iframe-dynamic consider using JavaScript to swap/navigate.

If iframe itself does not prompt, there’s no way around that wile using iframes.

You could however add a small or non-visible video to the page with the iframe, so users are asked (are they asked automatically or when starting the video?) when loading the parent page.